# SQL Request - Get the title of the top message

Tags: php, mysql, sql, model-view-controller

So I'm coding an e-commerce website in PHP with a MVC structure.
I created a messaging system, more like conversation, looks like an iOS discussion. Thing is, to start a conversation with a vendor, or someone, yo have to put a Title, to define what the discussion is about.
In the mailbox, I made a request to get the last message of the discussion for displaying the good date & time of the last message, and if there is a new message ( read / no read ) in the discussion.

Here is the message table :

```
id  int unsigned    
title   varchar(128) NULL   
message longtext    
sender_id   int unsigned    
recipient_id    int unsigned    
is_read tinyint unsigned [0]    
created_at  timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]   
updated_at  timestamp NULL
```

The user table :

```
id  int unsigned    
email   varchar(128)    
firstname   varchar(64) 
lastname    varchar(64) 
password    varchar(60) 
picture varchar(64) 
role    enum('User','Vendor','Admin')   
activation_code varchar(256)    
status  enum('not verified','verified') 
otp int 
created_at  timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]   
updated_at  timestamp NULL  
adress_id   int unsigned NULL
```

And my SQL request to get the last message of all conversations, that I'm displaying in mailbox with a foreach

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, m.*
FROM app_user u
INNER JOIN message m ON u.id = m.sender_id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT sender_id,
MAX(created_at) AS created_at
FROM message
GROUP BY sender_id
) r ON m.sender_id = r.sender_id
AND m.created_at = r.created_at
WHERE m.recipient_id = '. $recipient_id .'
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
```

Problem is I take the last message of the conversation, and the Title is only in the first message of the conversation.
I tested a lot of things, either on SQL and PHP, but never works correctly.

In fact I want to do somthing like a forum, with the title of the topic, and then displaying the last message front of this.

Here is my mailbox page which is displaying list of conversations :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mailbox">
            <h2 >Boîte de réception <i class="fas fa-inbox"></i></h2>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="pict">Lu / Non lu</th>
                        <th>De</th>
                        <th>Sujet</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th class="pict">Supprimer</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <!-- MANAGE IF NO MESSAGES -->
                        <?php
                        // Check if have any message
                        if(!empty($receivedMessages)):
                        // For each message
                        foreach($receivedMessages as $currentMessage):
                        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- CHECK IF MESSAGE IS READ -->
                        <?php if($currentMessage->getIs_read() ==  0): ?>
                            <td class="pict"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></td>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <td class="pict"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i></td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        
                        <!-- NAME -->
                        <td><?= $currentMessage->firstname . ' ' . $currentMessage->lastname ?></td>

                        <!-- TITLE -->
                        <td><a style="font-size: 18px; color: white;" href="<?= $this->router->generate('msg-read', ['recipientId'=>$currentMessage->getSender_id()]) ?>"> FIX IT HERE </a></td>

                        <!-- DATE & TIME -->
                        <td><?= date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($currentMessage->getCreated_at())) ?></td>

                        <!-- DELETE CONVERSATION -->
                        <td class="pict"><a href="<?= $this->router->generate('msg-delete', ['recipientId' => $currentMessage->getSender_id()]) ?>"><i style="color: white;" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                    endforeach;
                    else :?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Vous n'avez pas de messages</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="new-mess">
                <div class="return-back">
                    <a href="<?= $this->router->generate('main-home') ?>">
                        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                        <p>Retour à l'accueil</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="mess-elements">
                    <a href="<?= $this->router->generate('msg-new') ?>">
                        <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                        <p>Nouvelle discussion</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It maybe easy, maybe I'm looking too far, but I'm really blocking there...
Thanks to you

Comment: So there can only ever be one conversation between a specific pair of sender and receiver? I.e, when `S` and `R` have started a conversation under the title `Foo`, there won't ever be a second one between those two, under a different title `Bar`? Because if that is not the case, then I don't see how you would want to find the "first" message within a conversation to begin with. (Other than by going, "first" messages are all those, that _do_ have a title. But then you would still not know if any message send later, belonged to `Foo` or `Bar` now.)

Comment: Yes that’s it! You’re right. There can be just one discussion between two persons. Like Messenger or your phone

Comment: Maybe try a subselect that simply looks for the oldest matching message then? Although it would probably make more sense to separate this into a `conversation` and a `message` table to begin with.

Comment: Hmmm like making a conversation table with a title, the two persons id's and the messages related with the conversation ID .?